# How to get $_SESSION['id'] from a session

Tags: php

Hello I have 2 tables in my database one for courses and one for users, each of them has an id column.

I am trying to create a relationship between them, one user subscribe to one course. The result I am trying to store inside a 3rd table called subscription, which has a column for the course ID and column for user id.

The users are registering after passing log-in which is connected with a new session. After user click subscribe link which is

`<a href='subscribe.php?id=".$row['id']."'>subscribe!</a>`

they are taken to the backend php page where it is the inserted into database information:

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>
   $userid = $_SESSION['userID'];    
   $cursoid = $_GET['id'];

    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()) ; 


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `subscriptions` 
                     (curso_id, user_id) 
                     VALUES ('$cursoid', '$userid ')")
                         or die(mysql_error());
```

at this point I have obtained the id of the course and it is inserted inside it, the problem is for the user ID I am not getting anything. How I can get the id for the current logged in user ?

here is the code of my class for the login function:

```
    public function userLogin() {
$success = false;
try{
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();

$valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if( $valid ) {
$success = true;

}


$con = null;
return $success;
}catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
return $success;

$user = $stmt->fetchObj();

    if( $user->user_id > 0 ) {

        $success = true;

        // User has been successfully verified, lets sessionize his user id so we can refer to later
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $user->user_id;}

}
}
```

and finally here is the code of the login function:

```
session_start();
$usr = new Users;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
    header( 'Location: cursos.php' ) ;
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: You should read up on SQLinjection before you get yourself into some big time trouble. Also mixing `mysql_*` and `PDO`....You are not the original programmer of this code are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT be using sessionIds as userIds, instead you should be using the primary key of the user table after you have inserted the user row. Also, probably being pedantic, but you should rename your user variable to `$user`, `$usr` makes me wince.

Another way to get session id is: [session_id](https://www.php.net/session_id)

-- Edit --

```
public function userLogin() {

    ....

    $user = $stmt->fetchObj();

    if( $user->user_id > 0 ) {

        $success = true;

        // User has been successfully verified, lets sessionize his user id so we can refer to later
        $_SESSION['userId'] = $user->user_id;
    }
}

// We sessionized user id after validation, so we now have access to it
$userid = $_SESSION['userId'];

// Using straight mysql api is frowned upon, this should be converted to PDO before production use
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `subscriptions` (curso_id, user_id) VALUES ('$cursoid', '$userid ')")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: in my users first column is "userID" this is primary key also primary key is username but since duplicated usernames are alowed I guess that userID will be the best case, so how to use this as a primary key inside the subscription.php for the current logged in user and put it inside the new table subscription inside the column user_id

Comment: You can only have one primary key per table, however you can have a composite primary key, but that's not what you need in this sitch. What you want is an `id` column in the user table which is unsigned, not null auto_increment. Then you can add a `user_id` column to the subscription table. Then add a FK relationship between subscript table and user table, this way if any users are deleted, you won't have orphaned rows in the subscript table. But for this to work your tables have to be InnoDB. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: When a user logs in, you can store their `user_id` in their session, so if they click on a subscription, you can reference it for insertion into the subscript table.

Comment: that's the problem how to store the user_id after the user is loged in and in what should I store it, so than how should I call it back into to the SQL INSERT query.

Comment: I am inserting $userid = $_SESSION['userID']; into subscrption.php but in this line I am getting the following error: Notice: Undefined index: userID in D:\xampp\htdocs\cedecap\subscribe.php on line 13

Comment: Right, you have to make sure you reference the same index you assigned after validation. So after validation if you did: `$_SESSION['userId'];` then you need to refer to `$_SESSION['userId']`, i.e. camel casing must match.

Comment: Another question In the code we are using  $_SESSION['userId'] = $user->user_id;
but from where this is getting the variable of the userID column from the mysql table ?

Comment: I did added the Validation code as well inside the users class, it is upaded also here in the question but I am not sure if the validation is working corectly.

Comment: I am trying to check the varible to see if there is anything inside it with $userid = $_SESSION['userID'];
var_dump ($userid);  and the result is NULL

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: array(3) { ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(9) "vladicorp" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" }

Comment: added the follwing inthe login form: $_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID'];
and now the result is array(4) { ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(9) "vladicorp" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" ["userID"]=> NULL }

Comment: You get it sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to work with a session, you must call [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function at the beginning of the file. You called it in login function, but don't call in subscribe.php. Try this:

```
session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$cursoid = $_GET['id'];
//rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you have a minor error here as well, you had a space in this line `VALUES ('$cursoid', '$userid ')")`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `subscriptions` 
             (curso_id, user_id) 
             VALUES ('$cursoid', '$userid')")
                 or die(mysql_error());
```